# Order of operations term

Tags: terminology, arithmetic

What is the single-word term for "order of operations" in English, if there is one of course?
I am debating this with colleague and we don't know if such term exists in English math literature.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you use that phrase in a sentence? It might be easier then to see if there's a one-word equivalent.

Comment: Just a guess: Do you mean "precendence"?

Answer (score 3):

In 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations

> The order of operations, or precedence...